# Creating a priority queue containing unique elements

Tags: c++, vector

I want to create a priority queue containing unique elements. I could find that a queue containing unique vector elements can be created as follows:

```
template <typename T>
class queue1 {
private:
    std::queue<T> m_queue;
    std::set<T> m_set;
public:
    bool push(const T& t) {
        if (m_set.insert(t).second) {
            m_queue.push(t);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
};

queue1<vector<unsigned> > queueUnique;
```

But my requirement is in addition to the queue containing unique vector elements it should be a priority queue as each vector in my queue has a score associated with it. I tried to create this queue using:

```
priority_queue<queueUnique, vector<queueUnique>, ComparisonFunction> pq;
```

However this seems to be incorrect as it gives a queue of queue.

I am not getting as to how should I associate score with each vector, such that the resulting queue which I get is a priority queue with unique vector elements. For example if my queue is:

```
struct myDS{
  vector<unsigned> vec;
  double score;
};
queue<myDS> myqueue;
vector<unsigned> dummyVec1;
dummyVec1.push_back(5);
myDS obj;
obj.vec=dummyVec1;
obj.score=0.9;
vector<unsigned> dummyVec2;
dummyVec2.push_back(5);
myDS obj2;
obj2.vec=dummyVec2;
obj2.score=0.9; //with duplicate values score is always same so can be eliminated
```

Then how can I create a priority queue which is ordered on obj.score and yet does not contain duplicate elements. For example, myqueue above should contain "5" only once.

Comment: How do you calculate the score of a given vector?

Comment: @Galik Thanks for the reply. The score is generated randomly for each unique vector

Comment: Also, when you say "unique vector elements" do you mean "no two vectors with the same score" or "no two scores with the same vector" or both?

Comment: @Galik both. by default when two vectors are same, then they also have the same score associated with them. So, in this way they are correlated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that the score associated with each `std::vector` is unique it should be sufficient to add a comparator function to your `struct myDS` so that the `std::priority_queue` can determine the ordering:

Something like this:

```
struct myDS
{
    std::vector<unsigned> vec;
    double score;

    // Comparison function for ordering
    // based on score 
    bool operator<(const myDS& rhs) const
    {
        return score < rhs.score;
    }
};

template<typename T>
class queue1
{
private:

    std::priority_queue<T> m_queue;
    std::set<T> m_set;
public:
    bool push(const T& t)
    {
        if(m_set.insert(t).second)
        {
            m_queue.push(t);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
};

queue1<myDS> queueUnique;
```

Comment: Is it possible to traverse this priority queue without popping out elements. If yes, then how

Comment: @JannatArora No, that's not possible unfortunately.

Comment: @JannatArora Perhaps you could put your elements into a `std::set` rather than a `std::priority_queue` and just remove the highest value element when you need it?

Answer (score 0):

As Galik commented - what you're looking for is an ordered set:

```
#include <set>

struct ComparableThingy{
  ComparableThingy(std::string const& n, unsigned v):name(n),value(v){}
  std::string name;
  unsigned value;
  bool operator <(ComparableThingy const& other)const{return value<other.value;}
};

inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, std::set<ComparableThingy> const& s){
   for(auto const& v:s) out << v.name << "," << v.value << " ";
   return out;
}

int main()
{
 std::set<ComparableThingy> s;

 s.emplace("a",3);
 s.emplace("b",2);
 s.emplace("c",3);
 s.emplace("d",1);

 std::cout << s << "\n";

 // Equivalent to "pop"
 std::cout << "pop...\n";
 s.erase(s.begin());

 std::cout << s << "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
d,1 b,2 a,3   
pop...
b,2 a,3
```